# Custom DataGenerator - model.fit_generator: TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, function, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I created the following model:

```
def create_model(input_shape = (7, 7, 1280)):
    input_img = Input(shape=input_shape)
    backbone = Flatten(input_shape(7, 7, 1280)) (input_img)

    branches = []
    for i in range(8):
            branches.append(backbone)
            branches[i] = Dense(16000, activation = "relu", name="branch_"+str(i)+"_Dense_16000")(branches[i])
            branches[i] = Dense(128, activation = "relu", name="branch_"+str(i)+"_Dense_128")(branches[i])
            branches[i] = Dense(36, activation = "softmax", name="branch_"+str(i)+"_output")(branches[i])
        
    output = Concatenate(axis=1)(branches)
    output = Reshape((8, 36))(output)
    model = Model(input_img, output)

    return model

model = create_model()
```

I now would like to apply this model to data which is generated by a `Generator` in batches. Therefore I used the suggested `DataGenerator`from mujjiga with a small modification in `def __getiteam__`:

```
class DataGenerator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, X, y, batch_size):
        self.X = X
        self.y = y
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.X))

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.floor(len(self.X) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        idx = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]
        idx = int(idx)    
        batch_X, batch_y = self.X[idx], self.y[idx]
        batch_X = np.array(batch_X)
        batch_y = np.array(batch_y)
        return batch_X, batch_y
```

After this, I applied the DataGenerator to `X_after_efn_train`, `y_train`, `X_after_efn_val` and `y_val`. `X_after_efn_train` and `X_after_efn_val` are of shape `(n, 7, 7, 1280)` and the X values after running the pretrained EfficientNet model on them (https://keras.io/api/applications/efficientnet/#efficientnetb0-function).

```
training_generator_after_efn = DataGenerator(X_after_efn_train, y_train, batch_size=32)
validation_generator_after_efn = DataGenerator(X_after_efn_val, y_val, batch_size=32)
```

I compiled the model with this code:

```
model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Now, I tried to use `model.fit_generator`:

```
model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator_after_efn,
                    validation_data=validation_generator_after_efn,
                    steps_per_epoch = num_train_samples // 32,
                    validation_steps = num_val_samples // 32,
                    epochs = 10, workers=6, use_multiprocessing=True)
```

And got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-120-682a3512f3ac> in <module>()
      3                     steps_per_epoch = num_train_samples // 32,
      4                     validation_steps = num_val_samples // 32,
----> 5                     epochs = 10, workers=6, use_multiprocessing=True)

8 frames
<ipython-input-117-49b8453acf0a> in __getitem__(self, index)
     11     def __getitem__(self, index):
     12         idx = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]
---> 13         idx = int(idx)
     14         batch_X, batch_y = self.X[idx], self.y[idx]
     15         batch_X = np.array(batch_X)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Lets first try to reproduce the issue. Please feel free to update the collab notebook to reproduce the issue https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Old4vlMjTeSg3FTtrRMasNxRCgAlIsb-?usp=sharing

Comment: y_train and y_val are lists. They contain the one hot encoded labels. I changed their types to arrays, but got the same error. But I will try to update the Colab notebook. Thank you very much for your help. What I don't understand is: `y_val = np.random.randint(0, 2, (10, 8, 36))`. What does `(0, 2, (...))` mean?

Answer (score 1):

#### Model (scale down version)

```
def create_model(input_shape = (7, 7, 8)):
    input_img = keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    backbone = keras.layers.Flatten()(input_img)

    branches = []
    for i in range(8):
            branches.append(backbone)
            branches[i] = keras.layers.Dense(16, activation = "relu", name="branch_"+str(i)+"_Dense_16000")(branches[i])
            branches[i] = keras.layers.Dense(8, activation = "relu", name="branch_"+str(i)+"_Dense_128")(branches[i])
            branches[i] = keras.layers.Dense(4, activation = "softmax", name="branch_"+str(i)+"_output")(branches[i])
        
    output = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)(branches)
    output = keras.layers.Reshape((8, 4))(output)
    model = keras.models.Model(input_img, output)

    return model

model = create_model()
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')
```

#### Dummy Data

```
X_train = np.random.randn(100,7,7,8)
X_val = np.random.randn(100,7,7,8)

y_train = np.random.randn(10,8,4)
y_val = np.random.randn(10,8,4)
```

#### Data Generator

```
class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, X, y, batch_size):
        self.X = X
        self.y = y
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.X))

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.floor(len(self.X) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        idx = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]    
        batch_X, batch_y = self.X[idx], self.y[idx]
        return batch_X, batch_y
```

#### Finally fit the model

```
training_generator = DataGenerator(X_train, y_train, batch_size=8)
validation_generator = DataGenerator(X_val, y_val, batch_size=8)

model.fit_generator(training_generator,epochs=10, validation_data=validation_generator)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! When trying to run `model.fit_generator`I got this error: `------------
8 frames
<ipython-input-99-836b28fb3599> in __getitem__(self, index)
     11     def __getitem__(self, index):
     12         idx = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]
---> 13         batch_X, batch_y = self.X[idx], self.y[idx]
     TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

Comment: I used this code: `training_generator_after_efn = DataGenerator(X_after_efn_train, y_train, batch_size=32)
validation_generator_after_efn = DataGenerator(X_after_efn_val, y_val, batch_size=32)`, compiled the model as you stated and used the fit_generator: `model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator_after_efn,
                    validation_data=validation_generator_after_efn,
                    steps_per_epoch = num_train_samples // 32,
                    validation_steps = num_val_samples // 32,
                    epochs = 10, workers=6, use_multiprocessing=True)`

Comment: `X_after_efn_train.shape` is `(5000, 7, 7, 1280)` and `type(X_after_efn_train)` is `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: check the type of `idx` if it is float then convert it into int `idx = int(idx)`

Comment: Ok, thanks! Now, I get: `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Comment: Please update the question with latest code and the error as a edit.